# Rails 6 "//= require loader" in Application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have `//= require loader` in my application JS file and I want to see the file. I do not see it in my JS folder. Where else could it be? How to I find the path to it?

Comment: If it isn't in your ``app/assets``, check under ``lib/assets`` and ``vendor/assets`` -- Sprockets uses those in its search path as well.

Comment: Vendor assets! Thank you